# Sanity groupProblems.js error when running graphql deploy

Tags: graphql, sanity

Has anyone run into 'Cannot read property 'problems' of undefined?

happening into /node_modules/@sanity/schema/lib/sanity/groupProblems.js when trying to run graphql deploy

I can provide more info on what I added to the schema but it's nothing related to groupProblems I added. Not even sure what that module is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: fixed it, it was due to an extra comma in my schema

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: It was due to an extra comma in my schema.